# How to escape this command in qt?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to execute the following line inside my program:

```
 QString cmd;
 cmd = for /f "tokens=2,3 delims==" %%a in (temp3.txt) do (echo %%a >> list.txt) ; // how?
```

When I use escaping as follows

```
cmd = "for /f \"tokens=2,3 delims==\" %%a in (temp3.txt) do (echo %%a >> list.txt)";
```

I get `%%a not expected at this time` error message.

Running only this line by copy-pasting into .bat file does the job.

How can I solve this?

Comment: ... you're wondering why batch file syntax doesn't work with a C++ compiler?

Comment: This is the last step of the commands. The others work, but this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it from `%%a` to `%a` in both places. You only need to double-escape variables inside a bat file.

If you paste the line into a bare cmd prompt, you'll see the same error. Changing it to `%a` should fix it in the cmd prompt, and also in your program.

Comment: Yes exactly. I just found 1 minute before you replied :).